# stepSize for RatingBar between 0 and 0.5?

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I'm trying to get a small rating bar to display values like 3.2/5 or 4.7/5 rather than rounding to the nearest 0.5. I've tried setting stepSize in java and xml but it rounds every time.

```
                <RatingBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small"
                    android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="0.10"/>
```

I have not found anything to say that 0.5 is the max step size - in fact looking at the code itself for ratingBar it seems very clear that 0.1 would be acceptable. The theme"@style/RatingBar" simply describes background and foreground colours for the stars.

Comment: set step size dynamically like float rating = 2.25f; RatingBar.setStepSize((float) 0.2);

RatingBar.setRating(rating);

Comment: @janki unfortunately this does not work either, I have tried using RatingBar.setStepSize((float) 0.2) but it still rounds to 0.5.

Comment: Maybe it is related to issue with AppCompat: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197843 ?

Comment: @krossovochkin interestingly enough I had the same issues when I switched to activity. I have since created a view which paints 'filled' stars over 'empty' stars and has the function of being clickable and able to set rating dynamically. It's a little more verbose than just a rating bar but displays step size very accurately. Happy to share solution if anyone interested.

Comment: @GazBiz You can answer to your own question with solution that worked for you. It might be useful for someone